# Pale blue species forming during electrolysis of NaHCO3

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry, electrolysis, oxidation-state

I have a solution of 3500 ml $\ce{H2O}$ + 454 g $\ce{NaHCO3}$ in electrolysis at a potential of 12.5V using a lead anode and copper cathode. The surface areas aren't measured but they are enormous. I made the electrodes myself from lead and copper foil.

The idea was to make NaOH from $\ce{NaHCO3}$ (an inexpensive source  $\ce{NaHCO3}$ $$0.86/454g  and NaOH $7/500g) meanwhile producing the PbO<sub>2</sub> layer on the lead anode.

Everything seemed to be going as expected until I see there's a pale blue species being produced. What could it be? I'm thinking H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>, water having the potential to completely become peroxide, so I used the 5V output instead and the blue species vanished.

I've read electrolysis of salts in **basic** solution usually result in the salt reaching its highest state of oxidation at the **anode**.

Eg.:

$\ce{NaCl + H2O ->Cl- + OH- -> HClO + OH- ->ClO2- + H2}$ 
eventually becoming $\ce{ClO4-}$

(correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that's the way that reaction carries out),

or

$\ce{(NH4)2SO4 -> (NH4)2S2O8}$

**EDIT** 
It's just copper. Apparently in a solution of NaOH, there is some oxidation of a Cu cathode. I've seen it occur many times afterward. Hydrogen peroxide cannot be made without special laboratory equipment.

Comment: Wasn't there a copper wire?

Comment: copper cathode so nope, and remember the blue color comes back when it's reacted with something else. I also reacted it with ammonia with no tetraamine formation.

Comment: Well, if there was copper then however you did it, it's much more probable then any peroxides or other highly oxidated species (which aren't colorful BTW).

Comment: Copper oxidation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The blue color was caused by copper being stripped from the wire. btw, when your hair turns orange, it is because it is being stripped of color, among other other things (chemical bonds), which will cause it to be brittle and also absorb any hair dye to the extreme that it feels waxy...I'd suggest you cut off a piece of hair for a test before dunking your whole head in bleach (chlorine will turn it greenish).

P.S. Use nitric acid to dissolve Cu.

Comment: I actually use copper chloride, The fumes from Nitric acid are pretty nasty. I made some nitric acid with Calcium Nitrate and sulfuric acid. You could imagine the fun I had drilling the plaster out of my flask. lol. I just realized how old this question is. This is before I made reagent grade H2SO4 from magnesium sulfate.  Time flies.